# The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed. Affect running program

Tags: c#, entity-framework, objectdisposedexception

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

I was wondering if someone help me with this issue. Here is my code:

```
public partial class CustomerResearchForm : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
{
    FactorEntities contex;
    public CustomerResearchForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CustomerResearchForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void CResearchGrid_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerUpdateAndDelete CustomerUpdateAndDelete = new CustomerUpdateAndDelete();
        using (  contex =new FactorEntities())
        {       
            var sendergrid=(DataGridView)sender;
            int customercode = Convert.ToInt32(sendergrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
            var customer = from _customer in contex.tblCustomers where
               _customer.CustomerCode==customercode select _customer;

            CustomerUpdateAndDelete.tblCustomerBindingSource.DataSource = customer.ToList();
            CustomerUpdateAndDelete.Show();
            CustomerUpdateAndDelete.tblCustomerBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click+=tblCustomerBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click;
        }
    }

    private void tblCustomerBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contex.SaveChanges();    
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The exception occurs in this line:

```
contex.SaveChanges();
```

I can not use var for my context so what should I do?

Comment: you have your context wrapped inside of a using you do know that objects inside of `using() {}` do get auto-dsiposed, don't you?

Comment: do a `C# google search on the key word SCOPE`

Comment: dear @MethodMan I got it. I eliminated that from my code and error disappeared. but still after I edit contex info , it doesn't update my database! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `using` statement will automatically dispose `contex` at the end of your closing bracket `}` in `CResearchGrid_CellMouseDoubleClick()`

I'm not exactly sure what you are saving, but to get by, you should add a `using` statement and initialize your `contex` object. If you do go the route of initializing your `contex` in each method, you should remove it from your class member declarations. Note that you would need to modify your entities or add new entities to your `contex` object for you to actually save anything.  Without that, you're not really saving anything.

Another way to get going is you would initialize `contex` in your constructor and implement `IDisposable`. Then you can call `contex.Dispose()` in the `Dispose()` method.

Comment: @MethodMan you right about bracket . I wanna call my BindingNavigatorSaveItem and write my codes in its event so another method like( tblCustomerBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click )I need,I should think about a way which use my contex in my loop.